# Cannot add ssh key to ~/.ssh permanently

Tags: ssh, key, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using the Vector Robot OSKR kit with Ubuntu 20.04.  I have the public and private keys so I can ssh to Vector.  The problem is that I cannot do an ssh-add to get the keys to stay permanently in ~/.ssh. I've tried:

ssh-add -K - this gives back a "could not open a connection to your authentication agent" error.

The only way everything works is if I do ssh-agent /bin/sh, get a new shell and then I can add the key and ssh to Vector.  But that way does not seem permanent. I have to do it every time before every new SSH session.  I have done chmod to the key, it just seems to not want to be a permanent addition to my .ssh folder.  I've searched on here for a bit, and that's actually where I found out about the ssh-agent trick, but I'd really like to add this key so it's a permanent thing and I don't have to go through this process every time.

Comment: `ssh-add` doesn't add files to your `.ssh` directory; it sends them to an active `ssh-agent` process. It's not clear what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have this.  I opened a new session and it worked with no problem.  Not sure what else was going on, but it works now.  Most likely due to multitasking fat-fingering.